# Postfix can't send from localhost

Tags: postfix, debian-jessie

I have a newly installed Debian 8 server, created to replace an old postfix server running on Debian Lenny.  I've installed and reconfigured as needed the following newer packages on the new server:

- postfix 2.11.3-1
- dovecot 2.2.13-12~deb8u1
- amavisd-new 2.10.1-2~deb8u1
- spamassasin 3.4.0-6
- clamav 0.99.2+dfsg-0+deb8u2
- dkimproxy 1.4.1-3

I am able to send and receive mail between local users using both Thunderbird and Squirrelmail.  I can also send to external users using both mail clients.

What I cannot do is send to any user, including local users, from the server itself.  This affects not just the console program 'mail', but also daily reports sent via scripts called in cron jobs.  Attempts using 'mail' or via the script files trying to send to local accounts result in:

```
status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] refused to talk to me: 421 Internal error (Next hop is down))
```

## main.cf:

```
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 30000000

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = host.domain.com

myorigin = $mydomain

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8

relay_domains =

virtual_alias_domains = 

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10028
smtp-amavis_destination_concurrency_limit = 20

smtpd_helo_required = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = no

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.regexp
nested_header_checks =

smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        check_client_access    hash:/etc/postfix/GEN000_override,
        check_client_access  regexp:/etc/postfix/fqrdns.regexp,
        check_helo_access      hash:/etc/postfix/access,
        check_helo_access    regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_blacklist.regexp,
        check_sender_access    hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist,
        check_sender_access  regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_blacklist.regexp,
        check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/mx_access.txt,
        check_sender_access    hash:/etc/postfix/bdwl
        check_client_access    hash:/etc/postfix/broken_helos,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/filter_10026_catchall,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted,
        reject_unknown_client,
        reject_unknown_hostname,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,

smtpd_data_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining

debug_peer_level = 2

debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.1.5/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.1.5/README_FILES

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

## master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
        -o content_filter=dkimsign:127.0.0.1:10026
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient

scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000    1       tlsmgr

smtp-amavis unix -      -       n     -       2  smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       n     -       -  smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks

retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap

submission  inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_etrn_restrictions=reject
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o content_filter=dkimsign:[127.0.0.1]:10027
    -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject

dkimsign    unix  -       -       n       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords=8bitmime,starttls

127.0.0.1:10028 inet  n  -      n       -       10      smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

What I have determined through trial and error is that disabling this content filter in master.cf...

```
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
        -o content_filter=dkimsign:127.0.0.1:10026
```

...enables mail sent via 'mail' or cron jobs to be processed.  However the problem does not exist with that line enabled on the original postfix (2.5.5-1.1+lenny1) server.  Having inherited the old server, I'm not fully up to speed on what that line does, but the old server works and has been for years, so I don't want to blindly take the line out not knowing what I might break in the process.

Here is some of the output from netstat -tapn, showing that the server is listening on port 10026:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4404/postgrey.pid -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4731/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4699/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4385/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10026         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4424/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4699/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10027         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4442/perl
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10028         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4699/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3205/rpcbind
```

And here is the same from the original fully functional server:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3649/postgrey.pid -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4254/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3504/amavisd (maste
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4186/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10026         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4098/perl
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3573/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4186/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10027         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4106/perl
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10028         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4186/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4146/inetd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4254/dovecot
```

With the exception of the port for postgrey, I've made sure all of the 100xx ports match functions on both servers.

At this point I don't know where else to look.  Please help if you can!

Comment: I'll take a look at this when i get home this evening. I love solving these type of issues.

Comment: I'm still working on it, 421 errors are called "GreyListing". 

Greylisting is a method of defending e-mail users against spam. A mail transfer agent (MTA) using greylisting will temporarily reject" any email from a sender it does not recognize. If the mail is legitimate the originating server will, after a delay, try again and, if sufficient time has elapsed, the email will be accepted.

Comment: in your master.cf "-o disable_dns_lookups=yes"
should be:
" -o disable_dns_lookups=no"


When you disable DNS lookups, you must specify the relayhost as either a numeric IP address, or as a hostname that resolves to one or more IP addresses (with DNS lookup disabled, Postfix does no MX lookup).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer!  It turns out the previous admin neglected to include a section in master.cf to indicate the relay port that was specified in the dkimproxy_in.conf file:

```
# specify what address/port DKIMproxy should listen on
listen    127.0.0.1:10026

# specify what address/port DKIMproxy forwards mail to
relay     127.0.0.1:10029
```

Adding this section to master.cf cured the problem:

```
127.0.0.1:10029 inet  n  -      n       -       10      smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

Apparently the original system running on lenny somehow tolerates the omission without causing any problems or complaining in any way.

Thanks to those who took the time to read and/or reply!

Comment: Wow, Awesome, this will help a lot of people out for sure. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem that just doesn't have one solution.

change the following in your "main.cf" and let me know if it works for you, in your shoes, i would try the solutions one at a time to see which one is actually causing the error, (but if thinking out-loud) i think all of them should be changed.

**1.**

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

change to:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

**2.**

```
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8
```

change to:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

**3.** **add:**

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

**4.** **add:**

```
relayhost = [127.0.0.0]
```

***RelayHost Definition:***

*relayhost (default: empty)*

The next-hop destination of non-local mail; overrides non-local domains in recipient addresses. This information is overruled with relay_transport, sender_dependent_default_transport_maps, default_transport, sender_dependent_relayhost_maps and with the transport(5) table.

On an intranet, specify the organizational domain name. If your internal DNS uses no MX records, specify the name of the intranet gateway host instead.

In the case of SMTP, specify a domain name, hostname, hostname:port, [hostname]:port, [hostaddress] or [hostaddress]:port. The form [hostname] turns off MX lookups.

If you're connected via UUCP, see the UUCP_README file for useful information.

***Examples:***

```
relayhost = $mydomain

relayhost = [gateway.example.com]

relayhost = uucphost

relayhost = [an.ip.add.ress]
```

after looking at the relayhost examples i am almost tempted to offer a solution like:

```
relayhost = mynetworks
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply - definitely lots to think about/play with!  One thing I've been trying to understand is the purpose of the content_filter in my original post, which when removed, fixes the symptom.  Nothing I've read about DKIM shows any filtering on the pickup process - do you have any idea why that would be there? Also, as mentioned, this server was inherited, so I"m having to back-learn the thinking of its previous admin.

Comment: @bithead i studied this subject last night for 1-2hrs i am just about interested in a solution as you are. Ill see if i cant work on it more today again.

Comment: If found the solution and just posted it.  I'll still explore your other suggestions when time permits.  Thanks for your efforts!